# update table column with Cursor value

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor, sql-update

Hello I have a problem with cursors here I have this code in my PL/SQL

```
update CAND_ORDER SET SOURCE_SITE_ID = i.SITE_ID WHERE CAND_ORDER_ID IN
(select CAND_ORDER_ID from CAND_ORDER where SOURCE_SITE_ID is null and SP_TRIAL_MATERIAL_ID in 
(select SP_TRIAL_MATERIAL_ID from SP_TRIAL_MATERIAL where SP_RESEARCH_STATION_ID_SOURCE IN 
(select SP_RESEARCH_STATION_ID from SP_RESEARCH_STATION where SP_RESEARCH_STATION.CODE IN 
(SELECT SITE_CODE from SITE WHERE SITE.SITE_CODE=i.SITE_CODE))));
```

it gives an error saying:

```
PLS-00302: component 'SITE_ID' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 17, column 44:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "I"."SITE_ID": invalid identifier
```

which I totally do not understand would you please help pointing what is the problem

Comment: r u referring to a site_id from another table .as you are getting invalid identifier please provide the proper code or the structure of the tables (fields) which you are using

Comment: @user2940216 thanks I found that site_id as a field was not added on adding it it worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the error was in the cursor itself as SITE_ID was not added in the cursor as column. I added it and the problem was solved.